# R: Linear regression model does not work very well

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm using R to fit a linear regression model and then I use this model to predict values but it does not predict very well boundary values. Do you know how to fix it?

ZLFPS is:

```
ZLFPS<-c(27.06,25.31,24.1,23.34,22.35,21.66,21.23,21.02,20.77,20.11,20.07,19.7,19.64,19.08,18.77,18.44,18.24,18.02,17.61,17.58,16.98,19.43,18.29,17.35,16.57,15.98,15.5,15.33,14.87,14.84,14.46,14.25,14.17,14.09,13.82,13.77,13.76,13.71,13.35,13.34,13.14,13.05,25.11,23.49,22.51,21.53,20.53,19.61,19.17,18.72,18.08,17.95,17.77,17.74,17.7,17.62,17.45,17.17,17.06,16.9,16.68,16.65,16.25,19.49,18.17,17.17,16.35,15.68,15.07,14.53,14.01,13.6,13.18,13.11,12.97,12.96,12.95,12.94,12.9,12.84,12.83,12.79,12.7,12.68,27.41,25.39,23.98,22.71,21.39,20.76,19.74,19.49,19.12,18.67,18.35,18.15,17.84,17.67,17.65,17.48,17.44,17.05,16.72,16.46,16.13,23.07,21.33,20.09,18.96,17.74,17.16,16.43,15.78,15.27,15.06,14.75,14.69,14.69,14.6,14.55,14.53,14.5,14.25,14.23,14.07,14.05,29.89,27.18,25.75,24.23,23.23,21.94,21.32,20.69,20.35,19.62,19.49,19.45,19,18.86,18.82,18.19,18.06,17.93,17.56,17.48,17.11,23.66,21.65,19.99,18.52,17.22,16.29,15.53,14.95,14.32,14.04,13.85,13.82,13.72,13.64,13.5,13.5,13.43,13.39,13.28,13.25,13.21,26.32,24.97,23.27,22.86,21.12,20.74,20.4,19.93,19.71,19.35,19.25,18.99,18.99,18.88,18.84,18.53,18.29,18.27,17.93,17.79,17.34,20.83,19.76,18.62,17.38,16.66,15.79,15.51,15.11,14.84,14.69,14.64,14.55,14.44,14.29,14.23,14.19,14.17,14.03,13.91,13.8,13.58,32.91,30.21,28.17,25.99,24.38,23.23,22.55,20.74,20.35,19.75,19.28,19.15,18.25,18.2,18.12,17.89,17.68,17.33,17.23,17.07,16.78,25.9,23.56,21.39,20.11,18.66,17.3,16.76,16.07,15.52,15.07,14.6,14.29,14.12,13.95,13.89,13.66,13.63,13.42,13.28,13.27,13.13,24.21,22.89,21.17,20.06,19.1,18.44,17.68,17.18,16.74,16.07,15.93,15.5,15.41,15.11,14.84,14.74,14.68,14.37,14.29,14.29,14.27,18.97,17.59,16.05,15.49,14.51,13.91,13.45,12.81,12.6,12,11.98,11.6,11.42,11.33,11.27,11.13,11.12,11.11,10.92,10.87,10.87,28.61,26.4,24.22,23.04,21.8,20.71,20.47,19.76,19.38,19.18,18.55,17.99,17.95,17.74,17.62,17.47,17.25,16.63,16.54,16.39,16.12,21.98,20.32,19.49,18.2,17.1,16.47,15.87,15.37,14.89,14.52,14.37,13.96,13.95,13.72,13.54,13.41,13.39,13.24,13.07,12.96,12.95,27.6,25.68,24.56,23.52,22.41,21.69,20.88,20.35,20.26,19.66,19.19,19.13,19.11,18.89,18.53,18.13,17.67,17.3,17.26,17.26,16.71,19.13,17.76,17.01,16.18,15.43,14.8,14.42,14,13.8,13.67,13.33,13.23,12.86,12.85,12.82,12.75,12.61,12.59,12.59,12.45,12.32)

QPZL<-c(36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,36,35,34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16)

ZLDBFSAO<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
```

My model is:

```
fit32=lm(log(ZLFPS) ~ poly(QPZL,2,raw=T) + ZLDBFSAO)

results3 <- coef(summary(fit32))

first3<-as.numeric(results3[1])
second3<-as.numeric(results3[2])
third3<-as.numeric(results3[3])
fourth3<-as.numeric(results3[4])
fifth3<-as.numeric(results3[5])

#inverse model used for prediction of FPS
f1 <- function(x) {first3 +second3*x +third3*x^2 + fourth3*1}
```

You can see my dataset [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vlc5c6qO973vgIKZaadL5J5nz5hpFFFSua4P2Qb1Kig/edit?usp=sharing). This dataset contains the values that I have to predict.  The FPS variation per QP is heterogenous. See dataset. I added a new column.
The fitted dataset is a different one.

To test the model just write `exp(f1(selected_QP))` where selected QP varies from 16 to 36. See the given dataset for QP values and the FPS value that the model should predict.

You can run the model online [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=E5J5usMi&version=1).

When I'm using QP values in the middle, let's say between 23 and 32 the model predicts the FPS value pretty well. Otherwise, the prediction has big error value.

Comment: what is your question

Comment: @mtoto Thank you! I clarified it now.

Comment: might be more appropriate for http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please provide complete self contained code to perform your task that anyone else can simply copy and paste to their R session to see what you see.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I did it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the linear regression model I should use Weighted Least Squares as a Solution to Heteroskedasticity of the fitted dataset. For references, see [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350/lectures/18/lecture-18.pdf), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity) and [here](http://kurt.schmidheiny.name/teaching/heteroscedasticity2up.pdf).

```
fit32=lm(log(ZLFPS) ~ poly(QPZL,2,raw=T) + ZLDBFSAO, weights=1/(1+0.5*QPZL^2))
```

The other code remains the same. This model gives me lower prediction error than the previous.